# Linking libGLEW.so.2.0.5 to libGLEW.so.1.13

Tags: 17.10, shared-library

i'm using ubuntu 17.10 and in it i'm trying to launch a software called paintstorm. but I'm getting this error:

*error while loading shared libraries: libGLEW.so.1.13: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

I found out that I had to use ln -s command to link the already installed 2.0.5 version with the one that the program requires. But I think I failed to do so. And now every time I try the command in a different way, I get a message telling me that the 1.13 file already exists.

Can anyone tell me  how to do this correctly?

Comment: Delete the file : `cd [directory-with-libGLEW.so.1.13]/ && sudo rm libGLEW.so.1.13`

Comment: The `ln` command has a `-f` or `--force` option to "remove existing destination files"

Answer (score 4):

You use the force option `--force` or `-f` to overwrite any existing Symbolic Link.

For PaintStorm specifically, check what version of libGLEW you have:

```
ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep libGLEW
```

Use that version to create a symlink. In my case, I had `libGLEW.so.2.1`.

```
sudo ln -f -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLEW.so.2.1 /usr/lib/libGLEW.so.1.13
```

I also had this specific issue with PaintStorm, and this worked for me.